# solve expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: token

my code is

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct car
{
    int id;
     char carname[50];
    float price;
};

struct car add();
void accept();
void display(struct car c[],int n);

void main()
{
    struct car c[20];
    int opt,n;
    do
    {
        printf("\nWelcome\nEnter your choice\n1.Accept\n2.Display\3.Search\n4.Delete\n5.Exit");
        scanf("%d",&opt);
        swtich(opt)
        {
            case 1://Accept
                   n=0;
                   c[n]=struct car add();
                   n++;
                   break;
            case 2://Display
                   display(struct car c[],n);
                   break;
        }
    }while(opt!=5);
}

struct car add()
{
    struct car c1;
    printf("\nEnter the id");
    scanf("%d",&c1.id);
    printf("\nEnter the carname");
    scanf("%s",&c1.carname);
    printf("\nEnter the price");
    scanf("%f",&c1.price);
    retrun(c1);
}

void display(struct car c[],int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nCar id\tCar Name\tprice");
        printf("\n%d\t\t%s\t%d",c[n].id,c[n].carname,c[n].price);
    }
}
```

i cant get the code fixed by myself
i tried many thing neither of them worked for me...
please tell me what si wrong 
my exams are tomorrow and i cant get a simple program fixed
i am screwed
help me

i use dev c++ on windows 8.1 operating sys 32 bit

i tried the same code on ubuntu same error

error is shown on the line 23

this { is present on it

and the error is expected ';' before'{' token

P.S tell me where i was going wrong...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made a typo. `swtich` should be `switch` on line 22. I see a number of other compile error you'll find after that is solved. There is a similar typo around line 45. `retrun` needs to be `return`

Beyond that one error you'll have to deal with is calling functions and using return value.

For example:

```
c[n]=struct car add();
```

Should be:

```
c[n]=add();
```

You don't need to specify the type returned from a function like add() - the compiler already knows from the prototype  `struct car add();` that add returns a `struct car`.

Similar thing here:

```
display(struct car c[],n);
```

should simply be:

```
display(c,n);
```

Again the compiler knows that display takes an array of car structures from the prototype `void display(struct car c[],int n);` so you just have to specify a car array variable - `c` in this case.

Once the OP starts to play with his program there is a bug on this line that will produce undesired output, but I will leave that as an exercise for them to figure out:

```
printf("\n%d\t\t%s\t%d",c[n].id,c[n].carname,c[n].price);
```

Comment: We all have to learn somehow. Small typos can be hard to spot at times. When it comes to reading errors sometimes the problem appears to be on one line but the error comes from something above. If you get an error on a particular line and don't see an issue check the lines just above it as well.